# Search procedure based on pattern matching in sqlserver 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I made a procedure in ms sql server 2008 as :

```
CREATE PROC sp_search
@input varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1=@input OR col2=@input
END
```

Now IN the tbl1 has value as:

```
col1        col2
-------   ----------
in001      in-blr
in002      in-hyd
in003      in-kol
jp001      jp-hoc
jp002      jp-sng
-----     -------
-----     -------
au001     au-syd
```

like that.

Now my question is how can I create a procedure where I can give as **@input=in001** or **@input=in** or **@input=blr** or anything which will match and give output. I tried to give '*like*' but

`SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1 LIKE '%@input%'

OR col2 LIKE '%@input%'`
is not working. also I tried
`SELECT col1,col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col1=('%' + @input + '%') OR col2=( '%' + @input + '%' )` .
But it's also not working.
Please help me.

Comment: Did you try: `...where col1 like '%'+@input+'%' or col2 like '%'+@input+'%'`?

Comment: And say goodbye to IndexSeek :)

Comment: the comment above is how i would approach this although i would be careful about the proceedure usage and %in% would return XX-Xin or XX-inX along with in-XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_search 

@input VARCHAR(50)

AS BEGIN

     SELECT
           col1
         , col2
     FROM dbo.tbl1 t
     WHERE t.col1 LIKE '%' + @input + '%'
          OR t.col2 LIKE '%' + @input + '%'

END
```